# Converting Value to a Struct

Tags: go, go-reflect

I have a Struct which is as follows

```
type pathObject struct {
    s      *gizmo.Session
    finals bool
    path   *path.Path
}
```

I'm getting this struct and I need to extract the path object but I keep getting an compilation error

Here is my code for conversion

```
r := reflect.ValueOf(v)

for i := 0; i < val.NumField(); i++ {
    valueField := val.Field(i)
    typeField := val.Type().Field(i)
    val.Interface()

    if typeField.Name == "path" {
        log.Printf("typeName %v\n", typeField.Name)
        log.Printf("value %v\n", valueField)

        f := reflect.Indirect(r).FieldByName("path")

        log.Printf("CanInterface %v\n", valueField.Elem())
        p := valueField.Elem().(path.Path)

        //patObject := reflect.Indirect(valueField).FieldByName("path")

    }
    //f := valueField.Interface()
    //val := reflect.ValueOf(f)
    //slog.Printf("default %v\n", val)
}
```

I get an compiltion error on this line 
p := valueField.Elem().(path.Path) saying

```
invalid type assertion: valueField.Elem().(path.Path) (non-interface type reflect.Value on left)
```

Any clues how I can get past the error and get it to convert?

Answer (score 2):

Assert the type on the result of calling the [reflect.Value Interface() method](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.Interface).  The Interface() method returns the actual value.

```
p := valueField.Elem().Interface().(path.Path)
```

The path field must be exported to access the value:

```
type pathObject struct {
    s      *gizmo.Session
    finals bool
    Path   *path.Path
}
```

Try this simpler code:

```
func getPath(v interface{}) *path.Path {
    r := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(v))
    f := r.FieldByName("Path")
    return f.Interface().(*path.Path)
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/li86OSc0KI)

Comment: By way of explanation: as the error indicates, `Elem()` gives you a `reflect.Value`, which is a `reflect` *representation* of the value, *not* the value itself. You can call `Interface()` on a `reflect.Value` to get the value itself (typed as `interface{}`), which you can then cast to the underlying type as shown in the answer.

Comment: This works fine. When I try to cast it, the cast fails, the reason being, there is a type which cannot be exported so I have to figure out how I can handle that.  Thanks for your help